# SharePoint 2010 - Disable approval workflow and its automatic link to versions

Tags: 2010, workflow, metadata, approval-process, approval

I have an existing document library where the approval workflow is linked to the versions (which I belive is one of SharePoint's fundamental processes). I need to 'dismantle' this workflow for PDF documents so that once the document has been approved, you are then able to edit the meta data without having another approval workflow initiated.

Without knowing a lot about SharePoint, my initial thought would be to change the approval workflow from being linked to the version and link it to a different meta data column. Is this even possible? Would I need to create a new content type?